# Total value based on column conditional

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the following image, how could I get the values for cells C9, C10, C11?

[image]

In case it's not clear, what I need is for a function that will return the value of a cell in column C, depending on the value of the cell in column B.

The formula would need to be able to cope with a varying number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a big, unintuitive formula; likewise, it can be done very easily with a Pivot Table. Highlight the table and go to `Insert`, it is the far-left option.

[image]

Per your comment on the other answer, you can also count the number of rows used in the summation like so:

[image]

Comment: After you've inserted the table and then edit a value, it doesn't update your Pivot Table?

Comment: If you change the values that the pivot table references, you'll need to go to the pivot table options (Purple section of the ribbon bar) and hit "Refresh" (shortcut: select inside pivot table then press alt, then J, T, F, R)

Answer (score 0):

There are many such formulas, for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7="RM24")*(C2:C7))
```

To get the total weights for all the *RM24*.  You could set the range to slightly more than you actually need and put the criteria in a separate cell.